# Issues with Facebook oauth with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I'm experiencing some odd behavior with PHP SDK oauth to Facebook. While in Firefox, I was able log in and allow the app. I was redirected to my test page where I was outputting my user id, user info, etc. Beautiful!

Next, I open up Chrome or IE or Safari, and after logging into Facebook, I was redirected to the same page, but this time, I'm not shown as logged in. No user id, I can verify that I was logged into Facebook.

Things get weirder. I go back to Facebook on Firefox log out, go back to my test script, and it still shows me as logged in.. even if I completely log out via LogOutURL. After issuing $facebook->destroySession(); which finally showed me properly logged out.. now I can't login with any browser.

I've verified that I have a proper Access Token, and notice that the 'state' variable in the Login URL keeps changing with each page refresh on my test page.

Any ideas?

This is my test code.. obviously appid and secret have been removed. App has been created and looks to be working via Facebook... like I said, it worked once.

```
<?
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'blahblahblah';
$config['secret'] = 'blahblahblah';
$config['canvas'] = false;
$config['fbconnect'] = true;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

var_dump($facebook);
echo '<br /><br />';

echo 'Access Token<br />';
var_dump($facebook->getAccessToken());

echo '<br /><br />';


echo 'Login Status URL<br />';
var_dump($facebook->getLoginStatusUrl());

echo '<br /><br />';

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
echo 'login URL: '.$loginUrl;
echo '<br />';
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
echo 'logout URL: '.$logoutUrl;


echo '<br />';

$user = $facebook->getUser();

echo var_dump($user);


echo '<br />';

$user = $facebook->api('/me');

var_dump($user);

//$facebook->destroySession();
?>
```

Comment: I hate facebook's API.  That is all.  Good luck.  I hope you get it solved.  I will be watching in anticipation.

Comment: Use a try/catch block to throw any Facebook API Errors. There is most likely an error either in browser console or PHP error_log to be seen

Comment: No error at all, UserID just returns as int(0). I tried the try/catch. $facebook->getUser() is just return 0. I'm 100% logged in, and I'm not getting sent to login via getLoginUrl()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I saw these in the logs:

```
 CSRF state token does not match one provided.
```

The problem was related to multiple 'states'. My test script was echoing various calls to $facebook->getLoginUrl() which was apparently causing problems. I adjusted the test script to if $user was 'false' and if so, then call getLoginUrl() and redirect/authenticate... and return. This fixed the problem across the board.

Here is the link that helped ID this problem:
[CSRF state token does not match one provided FB PHP SDK 3.1.1 Oauth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977502/csrf-state-token-does-not-match-one-provided-fb-php-sdk-3-1-1-oauth-2-0)