# getUser returns 0 when i use facebooks example

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I use facebook's example code and it returns 0. I found this in the error log. "CSRF state token does not match one provided." When i click login page just reload and generates a new state and code.

I have searched on google and I tried many things but it didn't work.

```
<?php
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it on live server or local host? If localhost what is the domain name you have provided on the setting page ?

Comment: Please tell [which of the many suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22CSRF+state+token+does+not+match+one+provided.%22+%5Bphp%5D) did not work for you (with reference and at which point). If you need support for facebook demo code from the facebook website, please contact facebook support directly as well.

Comment: It's live! @AbhikChakraborty I only have my domain on web url and my app domain like example.com. The URL I use the app on is dynamic generated..

Comment: Have you tried this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679318/fb-login-error-csrf-state-token-does-not-match-one-provided