# PHP: $facebook-getUser() always returning 0

Tags: php, facebook

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once 'Facebook/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(

    'appId' => "347086135470127",
    'secret' => "f6d61cc9688ca34a0765f2ddbb138998",
    'cookie' => true,
        'domain' => "tinser.host56.com"

));

$session = $facebook->getUser();
echo $session;

if($session == 0) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 
        'display' => 'popup',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://tinser.host56.com/lib/php/facebookinit.php'
        ));
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('redirect_uri' => 'http://tinser.host56.com/lib/php/facebookinit.php'));
    echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login with facebook</a><br><a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout with facebook</a>";
} else {
    $api = $facebook->api('me');
    print_r($api);  
}
?>
```

---

It says that CSRF state token is invalid. I tried to correct `getCode()` in base_facebook.php. It does not work. PHP SDK version: 3.2.3. I await your correspondance. Thanks

---

Comment: This might help [CSRF token invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340764/problem-with-facebook-login-not-matching-csrf-state-token)

Comment: Since you just exposed your app secret here, the first thing you need to do is reset it in your app dashboard, __now__.

Comment: Thanks for your hwlelp.